# Передача данных в php скрипт

Tags: php, html, form

Есть страница корзины:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Корзина. СелБытТех</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta property="og:title" content="Корзина. СелБытТех">
        <meta property="og:description" content="">
        <meta property="og:url" content="http://selbytteh.by/korzina">
        <meta property="og:image" content="/assets/templates/img/logo.png">

        <meta property="og:type" content="website">
        <meta name="yandex-verification" content="406f14e8c932ed99" />
        <meta name="google-site-verification" content="njs361bU5VbOLKITQbQR4WIlfbX7OUjgJwpOrzD9Gms" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="assets/templates/img/favicon.svg">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/templates/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <base href=""/>

        <!-- BEGIN NEW STYLES -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/templates/css/plugins.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/templates/css/app.min.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/templates/css/mymain.css">
        <!--my_main_css_SELTORG-->

        <!-- END NEW STYLES -->

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,500,700&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">

        
        <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
        <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
        new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
        'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
        })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-5TFGP6S');</script>
        <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
        <noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-5TFGP6S"
        height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
        <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
        <div class="wrapper">
        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
<p class="browserupgrade">Вы используете <strong>устаревший</strong> браузер. Пожалуйста, <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">обновите ваш браузер</a>.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <header class="header ">
            <div class="header__top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="header__top-inner ta-right">
                        <div class="header__top-element header__top-element--color">
                        <!--    <span>Бесплатная доставка по Минску, при заказе через корзину скидка 3%</span> -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="header__top-element">
                            <span class="icon icon-map"></span>
                            <span>г. Минск, ул. Бирюзова, д. 4/9, пом. 6</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="header__top-element">
                            <span class="icon icon-time"></span>
                            <span>Мы работаем с 9:00 до 21:00</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="header__middle">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row align-center">
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="logo">
                                <a href="index.html">
                                    <img class="logo__seltorg" class="logo__img" src="assets/templates/imgs/seltorg/seltorg_name.png" alt="СелБытТех" />
                                    <img class="logo__img--mobile" src="assets/templates/imgs/logo-mob.svg" alt="СелБытТех" />
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-10">
                            <ul class="header__middle-list">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="tel:+375297779759" class="header__middle-number">
                                        <span class="icon icon-mts"></span>
                                        <span сlass="header__numbers-element">+375(29)777-97-59</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="tel:+375292769666" class="header__middle-number">
                                        <span class="icon icon-mts"></span>
                                        <span сlass="header__numbers-element">+375(29)276-96-66</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="tel:+375296602130" class="header__middle-number">
                                        <span class="icon icon-a1"></span>
                                        <span сlass="header__numbers-element">+375(29)660-21-30</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="mailto:6637844@gmail.com" class="header__middle-number">
                                        <span class="icon icon-mail"></span>
                                        <span>seltorgby@gmail.com</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="header__bottom">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <nav class="header__bottom-catalog">
                                <a class="header-nav-btn js-nav-btn" href="javascript:;">
                                    <span class="burger-icon"></span>
                                    <span>Каталог</span>
                                </a>
                                <div class="nav-wrapper-mini">
                                    <ul class="nav"><li class="first level1 odd"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika.html">Сельхозбытовая техника</a><ul><li class="first level2 odd"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/zernodrobilki.html">Зернодробилки</a></li><li class="level2 even"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/inkubatory.html">Инкубаторы для яиц</a></li><li class="level2 odd"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/poilki-i-kormushki-dlya-inkubatorov.html">Поилки и кормушки для инкубаторов</a></li><li class="level2 even"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/kormoizmelchiteli.html">Кормоизмельчители</a></li><li class="level2 odd"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/separatory.html">Сепараторы для молока</a></li><li class="level2 even"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/maslobojki.html">Маслобойки</a></li><li class="level2 odd"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/doilnye-apparaty.html">Доильный аппарат </a></li><li class="level2 even"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/elektrodvigateli.html">Электродвигатели</a></li><li class="level2 odd"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/kukuruzolushhilki.html">Кукурузолущилки</a></li><li class="level2 even"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/agregaty-dlya-plyushheniya-zerna.html">Агрегаты для плющения зерна</a></li><li class="last level2 odd"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/elektropastuhi.html">Электропастухи</a></li></ul></li><li class="level1 even"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi.html">Товары для дома и дачи</a><ul><li class="first level2 odd"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/umyvalniki-dachnye.html">Умывальники дачные </a></li><li class="level2 even"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/avtoklavy.html">Автоклавы</a></li><li class="level2 odd"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/shkafy-dlya-gazovyh-balonov.html">Шкафы для газовых балонов</a></li><li class="level2 even"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/pressa-dlya-soka.html">Пресса для сока</a></li><li class="level2 odd"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/baki-dlya-dusha.html">Баки для душа</a></li><li class="level2 even"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/myasorubki-i-processory-pishhevye.html">Мясорубки и процессоры пищевые</a></li><li class="level2 odd"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/koptilni.html">Коптильни</a></li><li class="level2 even"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/letnie-dushevye-kabiny.html">Летние душевые кабины</a></li><li class="level2 odd"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/seyalki.html">Сеялки</a></li><li class="level2 even"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/sushilki-dlya-ovoshhej-i-fruktov.html">Сушилки для овощей и фруктов</a></li><li class="level2 odd"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/izmelchiteli-vetok.html">Измельчители веток и травы</a></li><li class="level2 even"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/rybochistki.html">Рыбочистка</a></li><li class="level2 odd"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/kartofelesazhalki.html">Картофелесажалки</a></li><li class="last level2 even"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/snegouborochnyj-infentar.html">Снегоуборочный инвентарь</a></li></ul></li><li class="last level1 odd"><a href="katalog/zapchasti-i-komplektuyushhie1.html">Запчасти и комплектующие</a><ul><li class="first level2 odd"><a href="katalog/zapchasti-i-komplektuyushhie1/zapchasti-i-komplektuyushhie-dlya-zernodrobilok.html">К зернодробилкам</a></li><li class="level2 even"><a href="katalog/zapchasti-i-komplektuyushhie1/k-inkubatoram.html">К инкубаторам</a></li><li class="level2 odd"><a href="katalog/zapchasti-i-komplektuyushhie1/k-doilnym-apparatam1.html">К доильным аппаратам</a></li><li class="last level2 even"><a href="katalog/zapchasti-i-komplektuyushhie1/zapchasti-i-komllektuyushhie-k-zernodrobilkam.html">К кормоизмельчителям</a></li></ul></li></ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="nav-wrapper">
                                    <div class="nav-container-links js-subcat-list">
                                        <div class="mobile-nav-header">Каталог</div>
                                        <ul class="nav"><li class="first level1 odd"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika.html">Сельхозбытовая техника</a><ul><li class="first level2 odd"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/zernodrobilki.html">Зернодробилки</a></li><li class="level2 even"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/inkubatory.html">Инкубаторы для яиц</a></li><li class="level2 odd"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/poilki-i-kormushki-dlya-inkubatorov.html">Поилки и кормушки для инкубаторов</a></li><li class="level2 even"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/kormoizmelchiteli.html">Кормоизмельчители</a></li><li class="level2 odd"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/separatory.html">Сепараторы для молока</a></li><li class="level2 even"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/maslobojki.html">Маслобойки</a></li><li class="level2 odd"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/doilnye-apparaty.html">Доильный аппарат </a></li><li class="level2 even"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/elektrodvigateli.html">Электродвигатели</a></li><li class="level2 odd"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/kukuruzolushhilki.html">Кукурузолущилки</a></li><li class="level2 even"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/agregaty-dlya-plyushheniya-zerna.html">Агрегаты для плющения зерна</a></li><li class="last level2 odd"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/elektropastuhi.html">Электропастухи</a></li></ul></li><li class="level1 even"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi.html">Товары для дома и дачи</a><ul><li class="first level2 odd"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/umyvalniki-dachnye.html">Умывальники дачные </a></li><li class="level2 even"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/avtoklavy.html">Автоклавы</a></li><li class="level2 odd"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/shkafy-dlya-gazovyh-balonov.html">Шкафы для газовых балонов</a></li><li class="level2 even"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/pressa-dlya-soka.html">Пресса для сока</a></li><li class="level2 odd"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/baki-dlya-dusha.html">Баки для душа</a></li><li class="level2 even"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/myasorubki-i-processory-pishhevye.html">Мясорубки и процессоры пищевые</a></li><li class="level2 odd"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/koptilni.html">Коптильни</a></li><li class="level2 even"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/letnie-dushevye-kabiny.html">Летние душевые кабины</a></li><li class="level2 odd"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/seyalki.html">Сеялки</a></li><li class="level2 even"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/sushilki-dlya-ovoshhej-i-fruktov.html">Сушилки для овощей и фруктов</a></li><li class="level2 odd"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/izmelchiteli-vetok.html">Измельчители веток и травы</a></li><li class="level2 even"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/rybochistki.html">Рыбочистка</a></li><li class="level2 odd"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/kartofelesazhalki.html">Картофелесажалки</a></li><li class="last level2 even"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/snegouborochnyj-infentar.html">Снегоуборочный инвентарь</a></li></ul></li><li class="last level1 odd"><a href="katalog/zapchasti-i-komplektuyushhie1.html">Запчасти и комплектующие</a><ul><li class="first level2 odd"><a href="katalog/zapchasti-i-komplektuyushhie1/zapchasti-i-komplektuyushhie-dlya-zernodrobilok.html">К зернодробилкам</a></li><li class="level2 even"><a href="katalog/zapchasti-i-komplektuyushhie1/k-inkubatoram.html">К инкубаторам</a></li><li class="level2 odd"><a href="katalog/zapchasti-i-komplektuyushhie1/k-doilnym-apparatam1.html">К доильным аппаратам</a></li><li class="last level2 even"><a href="katalog/zapchasti-i-komplektuyushhie1/zapchasti-i-komllektuyushhie-k-zernodrobilkam.html">К кормоизмельчителям</a></li></ul></li></ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mobile-nav">
                                        <ul><li class="first level1 odd"><a href="shema-proezda.html">Схема проезда</a></li><li class="level1 even"><a href="o-kompanii.html">O нас</a></li><li class="level1 odd"><a href="dostavka-i-oplata.html">Доставка и оплата</a></li><li class="level1 even"><a href="partnery.html">Сотрудничество</a></li><li class="last level1 odd"><a href="akcii.html">Акции</a></li></ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mobile-info">
                                        <ul class="header__middle-list">
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="tel:+375336728585">
                                                    <span class="icon icon-mts"></span>
                                                    <span сlass="header__numbers-element">+375(33)672-85-85</span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="tel:+375259433064">
                                                    <span class="icon icon-life"></span>
                                                    <span сlass="header__numbers-element">+375(25)943-30-64</span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="tel:+375444928585">
                                                    <span class="icon icon-a1"></span>
                                                    <span сlass="header__numbers-element">+375(44)492-85-85</span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="mailto:info@zernomol.by">
                                                    <span class="icon icon-mail"></span>
                                                    <span>info@zernomol.by</span>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="header__top-element">
                                            <span class="icon icon-cred"></span>
                                            <span>Рассрочка до 6 месяцев</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="header__top-element">
                                            <span class="icon icon-halva"></span>
                                            <span>“Халва” рассрочка на 2 месяца под 0%</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="header__top-element">
                                            <span class="icon icon-disc"></span>
                                            <span>При заказе через корзину</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                        <class class="col-md-9">
                        

                            
                            <nav class="header__bottom-nav">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="first level1 odd">
                                        <a href="/index.html">Главная</a>
                                    </li>
                                     
                                    <li class="level1 even dropdown">
                                        <div id="dropdown__jq"></div>
                                    </li>

                                    <li class="level1 odd">
                                        <a href="dostavka-i-oplata.html">Доставка</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="level1 even">
                                        <a href="#anchor__place">Схема проезда</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="last level1 odd">
                                        <a href="#anchor__about">О нас</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <class class="header__bottom-cart evoShop_cart">
                                    <a href="korzina.html">
                                        <span class="icon icon-cart">
                                            <span class="cart-count evoShop_quantity"></span>
                                        </span>
                                        <span>Корзина</span>
                                    </a>
                                </class>
                            </nav>
                        </class>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>



<main class="main">
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="h1">Корзина</div>

            <div class="cartBlock">

                <div class="cartWrap">
                    <div class="cartWrap__block">

                        <div class="evoShop_cart">
                            <div class="evoShop_items"></div>
                        </div>  

                    </div>
                    <div class="cartWrap__order">
                        <div class="white-cart">
                            <div class="h1">Оформление заказа:</div>
                            <form method='POST' class="cart__form" id="orderCartForm" action="send.php">
                                <input type="hidden" name="formid" value="orderForm">
                                <input type="hidden" name="evoShop_items_json" class="evoShop_items_json" value=''/>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="cart__columnTitle">Личные данные</div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="name">Ваше имя</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" value="" required>
                                            <div class="form-control-feedback"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="phone">Ваш телефон</label>
                                            <input type="tel" class="form-control phone-mask" name="phone" id="phone" value="" required>
                                            <div class="form-control-feedback"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group ">
                                            <label for="dopphone">Дополнительный телефон</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control phone-mask" name="dopphone" id="dopphone" value="">
                                            <div class="form-control-feedback"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="cart__columnTitle">Доставка</div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="delivery">Метод доставки</label>
                                            <select class="form-control js-select" name="delivery" id="delivery">
                                                <option value="Курьер">Курьером</option>
                                                <option value="Самовывоз">Самовывоз</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <div class="form-control-feedback"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group hidden js-if-delivery">
                                            <label for="delivery_city">Город для доставки</label>
                                            <select class="form-control js-select" name="delivery_city" id="delivery_city">
                                                <option value="РБ">Не Минск (укажите в адресе)</option>
                                                <option value="Минск">Минск</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <div class="form-control-feedback"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group hidden js-if-delivery" id="for_address">
                                            <label for="address">Адрес</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" id="address" value="" required>
                                            <div class="form-control-feedback"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="message">Комментарий к заказу</label>
                                            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" rows="3"></textarea>
                                        </div>  

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="cart__columnTitle">Оплата</div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="payment">Метод оплаты</label>
                                            <select class="form-control js-select" name="payment" id="payment">
                                                <option value="Наличными">Наличными при получении</option>
                                                <option value="Безналичными">Безналичными при получении</option>
                                                <option value="webpay">WebPay</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <div class="form-control-feedback"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <br>
                                        <div class="evoShop_cart">
                                            <div class="total-price" style="text-align:left">Итого: <b><span class="evoShop_total"></span></b></div>    
                                            <div class="total-price js-shipping-row" style="text-align:left">Доставка: <b><span class="evoShop_shipping"></span></b></div>  
                                            <!--
                                            <div class="total-price js-discount-row" style="text-align:left">Скидка: <b><span class="evoShop_discount"></span></b></div>    -->
                                            <div class="total-price" style="text-align:left">К оплате: <b><span class="evoShop_grandTotal"></span></b></div>    
                                        </div>  
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn evoShop_submit">Оформить заказ</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>  
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </section>
</main>

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="assets/templates/imgs/seltorg/seltorg_name.png" alt="zernomol"/></a></div>
                <div class="footer-block">
                    <p>Общество с ограниченной ответственностью «Сельторг»</p>
                    <p>Республика Беларусь, 220073, ул. Бирюзова, д. 4/9, пом. 6</p>
                    <p>УНП 192166430; 
                    
                    <p>Внесен в Торговый реестр РБ 15.03.18, № 408446;</p>
                    <p>Почтовый адрес: 220092, г. Минск А/Я 32;<br> эл. почта: seltorgby@gmail.com</p>
                    
                    
                    <img src="assets/images/pay-systems.png" alt="pay"/></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <nav class="footer-nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="first level1 odd"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/zernodrobilki.html">Зернодробилки</a></li>
                        <li class="level1 even"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/inkubatory.html">Инкубаторы для яиц</a></li>
                        <li class="level1 odd"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/poilki-i-kormushki-dlya-inkubatorov.html">Поилки и кормушки для инкубаторов</a></li>
                        <li class="level1 even"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/kormoizmelchiteli.html">Кормоизмельчители</a></li>
                        <li class="level1 odd"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/separatory.html">Сепараторы для молока</a></li>
                        <li class="level1 even"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/maslobojki.html">Маслобойки</a></li>
                        <li class="level1 odd"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/doilnye-apparaty.html">Доильный аппарат </a></li>
                        <li class="level1 even"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/elektrodvigateli.html">Электродвигатели</a></li>
                        <li class="level1 odd"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/kukuruzolushhilki.html">Кукурузолущилки</a></li>
                        <li class="level1 even"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/agregaty-dlya-plyushheniya-zerna.html">Агрегаты для плющения зерна</a></li>
                        <li class="level1 odd"><a href="katalog/selhozbytovaya-tehnika/elektropastuhi.html">Электропастухи</a></li>
                        <li class="level1 even"><a href="katalog/zapchasti-i-komplektuyushhie1/zapchasti-i-komplektuyushhie-dlya-zernodrobilok.html">К зернодробилкам</a></li>
                        <li class="level1 odd"><a href="katalog/zapchasti-i-komplektuyushhie1/k-inkubatoram.html">К инкубаторам</a></li>
                        <li class="level1 even"><a href="katalog/zapchasti-i-komplektuyushhie1/k-doilnym-apparatam1.html">К доильным аппаратам</a></li>
                        <li class="level1 odd"><a href="katalog/zapchasti-i-komplektuyushhie1/zapchasti-i-komllektuyushhie-k-zernodrobilkam.html">К кормоизмельчителям</a></li>
                        <li class="level1 even"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/umyvalniki-dachnye.html">Умывальники дачные </a></li>
                        <li class="level1 odd"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/avtoklavy.html">Автоклавы</a></li>
                        <li class="level1 even"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/shkafy-dlya-gazovyh-balonov.html">Шкафы для газовых балонов</a></li>
                        <li class="level1 odd"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/pressa-dlya-soka.html">Пресса для сока</a></li>
                        <li class="level1 even"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/baki-dlya-dusha.html">Баки для душа</a></li>
                        <li class="level1 odd"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/myasorubki-i-processory-pishhevye.html">Мясорубки и процессоры пищевые</a></li>
                        <li class="level1 even"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/koptilni.html">Коптильни</a></li>
                        <li class="level1 odd"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/letnie-dushevye-kabiny.html">Летние душевые кабины</a></li>
                        <li class="level1 even"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/seyalki.html">Сеялки</a></li>
                        <li class="level1 odd"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/sushilki-dlya-ovoshhej-i-fruktov.html">Сушилки для овощей и фруктов</a></li>
                        <li class="level1 even"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/izmelchiteli-vetok.html">Измельчители веток и травы</a></li>
                        <li class="level1 odd"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/rybochistki.html">Рыбочистка</a></li>
                        <li class="level1 even"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/kartofelesazhalki.html">Картофелесажалки</a></li>
                        <li class="last level1 odd"><a href="katalog/tovary-dlya-doma-i-dachi/snegouborochnyj-infentar.html">Снегоуборочный инвентарь</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>




<!-- BEGIN NEW SCRIPTS -->
<script src="assets/templates/js/plugins.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/templates/js/app.min.js"></script>
<script>
    try {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            document.querySelector('head').innerHTML += "";
            document.body.classList.add('loaded');
        });
    } catch (e) { }
</script>



</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/snippets/evoShop/evoShop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        evoShop({
                currency: "BYN",
                cartStyle: "div",
                cartColumns: [
                    { attr: "rowTpl", label: false, view: "rowTpl"},
                ],
                rowTpl: '<div class="item-image"><img src="http://selbytteh.by/%image%"></div><div class="item-infoRow"><div class="item-name">%name%</div><div class="item-price">%price%</div></div><div class="item-qRow-wrapp"><div class="item-qRow"><div class="item-decrement"><a href="javascript:;" class="evoShop_decrement">-</a></div><div class="item-quantity">%quantity%</div><div class="item-increment"><a href="javascript:;" class="evoShop_increment">+</a></div></div></div><div class="item-total">%total%</div><div class="item-remove"><a href="javascript:;" class="evoShop_remove">×</a></div>',
        });
        evoShop.ready( function(){
            $("#delivery").on("change", function() {
                if($(this).val() == "Самовывоз") {
                    $(".js-if-delivery").hide();
                    $("#address").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                } else {
                    $(".js-if-delivery").show();
                    $("#address").removeAttr("disabled");
                }
                evoShop.update();
            });
            $("#delivery_city").on("change", function() {
                evoShop.update();
            });
        
        });
        evoShop.shipping(function(){
            if( evoShop.quantity() > 0 && $("#delivery").val() == "Курьер" ){
                if($("#delivery_city").val() == "Минск") return 7;
                else return 15;
             } else {
                return 0;
             }
        });
        /*
        evoShop.discount(function(){
            if($("#delivery").val() == "Самовывоз" ){
                return 15;
             } else {
                return 0;
             }
        });
        */
        //скрываем корзину если там пусто
        evoShop.bind("update", function(){
          if( evoShop.quantity() === 0 ){
                $("#orderCartForm, .delivery-info, .total-price").hide();
                $(".evoShop_quantity").html("0");
          } else {
                $("#orderCartForm, .delivery-info, .total-price").show();
          }
        });
        //добавляем товары в корзину из локалстораже
        $(document).on("click",".evoShop_submit",function(ev){
                $(".evoShop_items_json").val( localStorage.getItem("evoShop_items").replace("}}","} }") );   
                //evoShop.empty();
        });
        
        
        
        //товар добавлен в карзину
        //$(document).on("click",".item_add",function(ev){
        //  alertify.logPosition("top left");
        //  alertify.success("Товар добавлен в корзину");
        //});
        $(document).on("click",".item_add",function(ev){
            alertify.success("Товар добавлен в корзину");
        });
        
        
   //$("#phone").mask("+375 (99) 9999999",{placeholder:" "});

        
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

И есть `php` скрипт отправки формы:

```php
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$tel = $_POST['phone'];
$dop_tel = $_POST['dopphone'];
$delivery = $_POST['delivery'];
$city = $_POST['delivery_city'];
$addres = $_POST['address'];
$comment = $_POST['message'];
$payment = $_POST['payment'];
$mail = "mail"
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
if (mail($mail, "Новый заказ", "Имя:".$name."\n. Телефон: ".$tel."\n. Доп.телефон: ".$dop_tel."\n. Способ доставки: ".$delivery."
\n.Город: ".$city."\n. Адрес: ".$addres."\n. Комментарий к заказу: ".$comment."\n. Способ оплаты: ".$payment, $headers))
 {
    header('location:spasibo-za-zakaz.html');
} else {
    header('location:error-zakaz.html');
}
?>
```

Все заполняемые поля скрипт успешно отправляет на почту, как к этому добавить вид товара и его стоимость? Есть `js` скрипт, который это все считает, как я понял, скрипт не мой, но все делается через `localstorage`.

Comment: Удалите всё, оставьте только нужный код.

Comment: @InDevX так тут вроде и так только то, что нужно

Comment: Нет. Тут всё что есть, а не что нужно. В корзине есть то что надо добавить или нет?

Comment: @InDevX в html'e нет, я его скинул, чтобы показать саму форму. Надо вытянуть стоимость и вид товара для  отправки в пхп скрипте

Comment: Тут скорее всего просят удалить лишний код html, оставить в нем только форму, а не весь сайт. Очень неудобно читать. Касаемо вашего вопроса, в вашем случае, нужно в форму добавлять скрытые поля со значениями цены и ссылки на картинку. А в php брать значения этих полей. Это не самое удачное решение, но для лучших решений нужен больший стек

Comment: @AlexandrOpekunov так в этом и вопрос, создам я в хтмле скрытые формы, а как туда получить из локалстореджа данные?

Comment: Почему вы получается стоимость и вид товара из localStorage. Логично же, что его нужно получать из базы данных. Я перешел на ваш сайт и посмотрел работу. Если вы будете брать данные цены из localStorage, то я могу спокойно зайти в браузере в инструменты разработчика и поменять цену на нужную мне. И тогда вам будет приходить неверная сумма.

Comment: @AlexandrOpekunov не знал об этом. Этот js скрипт - это готовое решение, поэтому его и использую. Не смотря на это, вы можете помочь?

Comment: Единственный безопасный способ получить правильную цену - делать на уровне PHP, все что передается из браузера легко изменить. Вам нужно понять как работает ваша база и подгружать оттуда

Comment: @AlexandrOpekunov я это понял, спасибо. Но меня интересует как решить вопрос конкретно с этими исходными данными